# String startsWith DRIVELETTER:\

Tags: java, string, startswith

Quick question in Java `String.startsWith()` which needs some sort of wildcard.

I need to check to see if a link starts with `http://` or a local drive (`c:\`,`d:\` etc) but I do not know the drive letter.

So I think I need something like `myString.startsWith("?:\\")`

Any ideas?

### Cheers

Cheers for that, but think I need to build on this a little.

I now need to cater for

```
1.http://
2.ftp://
3.file:///
4.c:\
5.\\
```

it's overkill but we want to be sure we've caught them all.

I have

```
if(!link.toLowerCase().matches("^[a-z]+:[\\/]+.*")) {
```

which works for any character or characters followed by a : *(example http:, ftp:, C:)* which covers 1-4 but I can't cater for \\

The nearest I can get is this (which works, but it'd be nice to get it in the regEx).

```
if(!link.toLowerCase().startsWith("\\") && !link.toLowerCase().matches("^[a-z]+:[\\/]+.*")) {
```

Comment: Use a regex, `startsWith` can't help you here.

Comment: Cheers guys, so many quick responses, but the one I'm going to go for is @Jack - ^[a-zA-Z]:\\\\.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), which is not supported by `startsWith`:

```
^[a-zA-Z]:\\\\.*

^   ^     ^    ^
|   |     |    |
|   |     |    everything is accepted after the drive letter
|   |    the backslash (must be escaped in regex and in string itself)
|  a letter between A-Z (upper and lowercase)
start of the line
```

Then you can use `yourString.matches("^[a-zA-Z]:\\\\")`

Comment: Thanks for this, this is the example I have gone along with and it appears to be working fine.  Just curious, why do you need \\\\ to represent \ in regex? I could understand \\ (to escape the \) but why four backslashes?

Comment: Because the \ is an escape character even in the regex, so the regex should be "\\" to indicate a single backslash. But to have \\ in a string you must escape them both so "\\\\"

Answer (score 2):

You should use regular expressions for this.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(http|[a-z]):");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if(m.find()) {
   // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String toCheck = ... // your String
if (toCheck.startsWith("http://")) {
   // starts with http://
} else if (toCheck.matches("^[a-zA-Z]:\\\\.*$")) {
    // is a drive letter
} else {
    // neither http:// nor drive letter
}
```